# How can I remove the "The image was resized to fit within the maximum allowed dimensions..." message without hacking core?

Tags: hooks

By default, Drupal prints out a notification message that images exceeding the maximum dimensions were resized.  I want to disable this message.

The relevant line is located in [file_validate_image_resolution()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_validate_image_resolution/7):

```
  drupal_set_message(t('The image was resized to fit within the maximum allowed dimensions of %dimensions pixels.', array('%dimensions' => $maximum_dimensions)));
```

Obviously, the quick way to do this is to put two little slashes right before the line.  But I am trying to do this without hacking core.  I copied the entire function into `MYMODULE_file_validate_image_resolution()`, then commented the lines out, but this had no effect.  What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Disable Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages) module helps you to disable any type of message in drupal.

It module has following features.

- Filter out messages that match a full text string exactly.
- Filter out messages that match a regular expression.
- Permissions to specifically hide all messages of a given type from
  any role.
- Disable all filtering for specific users.
- Disable all filtering for specific paths.
- Apply filtering only for specific paths.
- Debug system to get messages in the HTML without showing it to the
  end users.

Once you install the module you can see the configuration options at admin/config/development/disable-messages.

For your requirement just enter following text in "Messages to be disabled:" textarea.

```
The image was resized to fit within the maximum allowed dimensions of .*? pixels.
```

[image]

Note : Make sure necessary permission to be set like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook_file_validate like this.

```
function mymodule_file_validate($file) {  
  if (form_get_errors()) {

    // Save errors
    $form_errors = form_get_errors();
    $drupal_errors = drupal_get_messages('error');
    // Clear form errors
    form_clear_error();

    foreach($drupal_errors['error'] as $key => $error) {
      if (in_array($error, $form_errors)) {
        // Unset form errors
        unset($drupal_errors['error'][$key]);
      }
    }

    // Rebuild drupal errors
    foreach($form_errors as $key => $message) {
      if(strpos($message, 'old message') !== false) {
        $message = str_replace('old message', 'new message', $message);
        $_SESSION['messages']['error'][$key] = $message;
        form_set_error($key, $message);
      } else {
        form_set_error($key, $message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can remove the message in `hook_file_validate`, `hook_theme_registry_alter` or on page load:

```
  $message = t('YOUR MESSAGE');
  foreach ($_SESSION['messages']['status'] as $status => $statusmessage) {
    if ($message == $statusmessage) {
      unset($_SESSION['messages']['status'][$status]);
    }
  }
```

2) You can try to replace core validator of your image field widget with a custom one in `#upload_validators` using `hook_field_widget_form_alter`.

3) You can remove `file_validate_image_resolution` from `#upload_validators` and do your validation without message in `hook_file_validate`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to use a hook_form_user_register_alter to add your own submit handler, and within it be sure to call drupal_get_messages() with the clear_queue variable set to true. This will also clear out messages from the queue. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

alter the form your submitting

add another function in the $form[#submit] like so

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'yourFunction';
```

then and your function

```
function yourFunction(){
    drupal_get_messages();
    //you can also set your messages here.
}
```